# Storing debug session (breakpoint/bookmarks) in Visual Studio (C++)

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++

When I'm debugging something, I would like to store breakpoints/bookmarks related to bug* I'm currently working on. So when I switch to another bug*, I don't want every time to manually disable breakpoints/bookmarks related to previous bug, and create another one for the new bug. It would be great that is possible to tag breakpoint or bookmarks.

So far I overcome above by storing .suo file for every bug* I'm working on, but I found hard/awkward to handle multiple .suo files...

How do you handle above or does anyone know any VS add-on or some tool that does similar thing?

Thanks!

*bug - bug/issue/current_project/whatever